# SET NOCOUNT OFF disregarded in SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I want to see how many rows are affected for each DDL statement that is run by a query, so I set SET NOCOUNT OFF at the start of each query that is run.

Sample query:

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE dbo.tbProvClause SET ClauseTemplate = 'Clause1' where DocumentName = '\Templates\EndorsAccessPlainLanguageQCEng.CDS';
    UPDATE dbo.tbProvClause SET ClauseTemplate = 'Clause 2' where DocumentName = '\Templates\EndorsEnforcedRemovallLtdMktPublicPropertyQCEng.CDS';
    UPDATE dbo.tbProvClause SET ClauseTemplateFR = 'Malgré French Clause 1' where DocumentNameFR = '\Templates\EndorsAccessHOPPQcFr.CDS';
    UPDATE dbo.tbProvClause SET ClauseTemplateFR = 'Malgré les exceptions  Clause 2' where DocumentNameFR = '\Templates\EndorsEnlèvementFTNdomainepublicERLMPublicPropertyQcFr.CDS';  
   COMMIT TRAN
   PRINT 'Script Completed With Success - Changes committed on ' + CAST(current_timestamp AS varchar(25))
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   --
END CATCH

GO
```

and it returns

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Script Completed With Success - Changes committed on Nov 29 2017 12:10PM
```

This is good. But when I run the same in SQLCMD, I get only 1 row .i.e.

```
sqlcmd -S testserver -dTestDB -i StackOverflowSQL.sql

(1 rows affected)
Script Completed With Success - Changes committed on Nov 29 2017 12:24PM
```

How do I retain the ability of the SET NOCOUNT OFF in SQLCMD? The reason I asked this question is that I have a number of scripts that I want to batch using SQLCMD and I will be saving their logs. In this case, the SET NOCOUNT OFF is very useful in checking how many lines of *1 rows affected* will give a feedback that the run was successful.

Comment: found the solution.. Change the path and use the newer version of SQLCMD. I was using SQL Server 2008R2 version. SQL Server 2012 or later fixed the problem. See answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this and see if it works.

use `-v` (small letter v).

```
sqlcmd -v NOCOUNT=OFF -S testserver -dTestDB -i StackOverflowSQL.sql
```

Or

In the same command prompt first run `SET NOCOUNT=OFF` before calling `sqlcmd` .

Look into below documentation link and search for  "**Variable Precedence**". You will get some idea.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

Comment: Naidu, where do I use the NOCOUNT=OFF variable in the script?

Comment: In the file where you are calling SQLCMD, modify the statement to as shown in first option of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a hunch.  Remove the Go statement after "set nocount off".

First of all "set nocount off" statement does not require a GO.  Secondly, I think GO (A batch executor) may be setting the option only for that batch.

There is a rather stupid workaround if my suggestion does not work.
You can:
print @@rowcount 
after every sql statement which you may be interested to monitor the row counts.

Comment: your hunch did not work. I have done print @@row, but it is rather cumbersome and very repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  There were multiple versions of SQLCMD installed in the machine. To find out which version I was using:

```
E:\Test>where sqlcmd
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
```

The one that I was using was SQL Server 2008 R2 version. the I looked into the system environment variables PATH and changed the order and now it uses the SQL server 2012 version. After changing the PATH

```
E:\Test>where sqlcmd
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE

E:\Test>sqlcmd -S testserver -dTestdb -i StackOverflowSQL.sql

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)
Script Completed With Success - Changes committed on Nov 29 2017  3:37PM
```

It works!